# Reputation not changed when setting flair

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flair, combined-flair

I recently got enough reputation to set the flair option. I have more than 200 rep in two of the SO sites but when checking at the html picture links of the flairs that i got from SO, i noticed that in meta my flair is coming fine with correct reputation but in main SO, the reputation of the flair has not yet been updated even though it is showing correctly in my profile. I have 300 rep but it is still showing 190.

I am attaching the picture of my SO, meta and overall flair. The overall flair says that i do not have any attached sites with over 200 rep. But i have 205 rep in meta and 300 in SO.
[image]

Comment: Caching..the answer is always caching....

Comment: Flair images can be cached for up to a week. And the Stack Exchange (combined flair) data gets updated once a day.

Comment: Ya, but i went above 200 rep in main SO first. Because of that only did i reached 200 in meta. I will give it some time then..

Comment: @prince: maybe caching takes longer on the main site since it is under heavy traffic.

Comment: @juergend Ya, maybe that is the reason!